# Struts 2 action url mapping

Tags: struts2

I have enabled the Struts 2 convention plugin.

```
package system;

@Namespace("/customer")
public class IndexAction extends ActionSupport {
  public execute() {
    return SUCCESS;
  }
}
```

If I type `http://localhost:8080/customer/` and `http://localhost:8080/customer/index.action`, both can reach the same page.

How can I disable `http://localhost:8080/customer/` and only allow access using `http://localhost:8080/customer/index.action` ?

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean by "disable". All action configs are enabled by default and those created automatically.

Answer (score 0):

When invoking `http://localhost:8080/customer` Struts2 will find the Action (ie IndexAction) mapped with the corresponding namespace and redirect to the `execute()` (default) method.

If you don't want this behavior you can remove `execute()` and create a specific method in the class

```
public String index() {
  return SUCCESS;
}
```

The corresponding URL is `http://localhost:8080/customer!index` (`http://localhost:8080/customer!index.action` works too)